# How to troubleshoot NVIDIA Channel Exception?

Tags: opengl, nvidia

How should I go about debugging this?  At the moment I'm using the OpenGL Profiler, and printing logs to see what is happening.  However, it seems like the error is happening elsewhere, and I'm not sure how to go about figuring out what is causing the issue.

My code:

```
vertexCount = 3;
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,
};

/* Create Buffer -- (I know this shoudn't be done every frame, but I wanted to be sure the buffer wasn't getting lost somehow */
    GLuint buffer[1];
glGenBuffers(1, buffer);

// -- vertices
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * vertexCount, &vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

/* Render */
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
                      0,                                /* attribute */
                      1,                                /* size */
                      GL_FLOAT,                         /* type */
                      GL_FALSE,                         /* normalized? */
                      sizeof(GLfloat)*2,                /* stride */
                      (void*)0                          /* array buffer offset */
                      );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

if(glGetError())
    NSLog(@"Error!");
else
    NSLog(@"No error");
```

...and the console logs:

```
10/12/12 2:34:26.000 PM kernel[0]: NVDA(OpenGL): Channel exception! exception type = 0xd = GR: SW Notify Error
10/12/12 2:34:26.000 PM kernel[0]: IOVendorGLContext::ReportGPURestart 
10/12/12 2:34:26.000 PM kernel[0]: 0000006e
10/12/12 2:34:26.000 PM kernel[0]: 00100000 00008597 00000474 00000000
10/12/12 2:34:26.000 PM kernel[0]: 0000047e 00000904 00008000 0000000e
10/12/12 2:34:26.000 PM kernel[0]: 00000000 00000000 00000000
10/12/12 2:34:26.000 PM kernel[0]: 00000000 0000000c
```

Comment: What line is causing that? It seems like likely something went wrong inside the driver, perhaps a bug.

Comment: I'm not sure... console logs I place say I get through without error.

Comment: What if you step in debugger?

Answer (score 1):

If this is all of your relevant code, then you are generating more and more VBOs without ever deleting them again using `glDeleteBuffer()`, which probably causes the driver to panic after some time.

I had a similar issue where I was accidentally drawing and re-creating VBOs concurrently, which internally stacked them up until there were too many. This caused the same driver exception, freezing the screen or even auto-restarting my MacBook Pro.

Anyway, the NVidia driver shouldn't be freaking out this way. It's a shame.